# Wordpress sidebar positioning

Tags: html, css, wordpress, stylesheet

I have a sidebar which I want to postion at the left side of my content. I've tried everything I could think of but can't get the sidebar to show in the left part of the page.

```
    <div class="container">
        <header>

        </header>
    <?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'primary' ) )  {?>
 <div class='cats'>
    <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'primary' );  } ?>
  </div>
        <div class='content_wrapper'>
        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
        <?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>
        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

        <div class="posts">
            <article>
               <div class="wrapper">
               <h2 class='headline'><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"></h2>

                <div class='thumbs'>

                <p><?php echo content('120'); ?></p>
            </article>
            //.....
                    // some code
               </div>
            </div>
         ... some more code
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Please Put this after header, so you can have sidebar at left

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
```

and for dynamic side bar use this css

```
.container
{
    margin:auto!important;
}
.cats
{
    float:left;
    width:30%;
}
.content_wrapper
{
    float:right;
    width:68%;
}
```

Comment: I am using a dynamic sidebar so I am using the 
<?php dynamic_sidebar( 'primary' );?>
line to show the sidebar, Don't you think I need some css to change the sidebar position?

Comment: please provide me your site link then i'll help you

Comment: do you want to display category section to left ?

Comment: I can't get it to move to the left or the right, but i would prefer it at the left side

Comment: pls try css that i mention in my answer

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37810/discussion-between-farzan-and-ankit-agrawal)